# How to declare and use a variable in Aqua Data Studio querying an Oracle server

Tags: oracle, aqua-data-studio

In Microsoft SQL Server

```
DECLARE @var INT
SET @var = 1
SELECT @var
```

What would the equivalent statement be in Aqua Data Studio when querying an Oracle server?

I've tried different variations of this (with GO or ; as statement separators, nothing has worked so far).

```
DECLARE var INTEGER 
SELECT var FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 1):

use 'Parametrized Script' button in Query Analyzer. and var name with & in code:

```
select * from tabl where id = &id
```

More info:
https://www.aquaclusters.com/app/home/project/public/aquadatastudio/wikibook/Documentation11/page/51/5-5-Parameterized-Scripts

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use variable binding, but it does have a different syntax.  Try the below example query.

=== Query ===

.variable var1, VARCHAR, '10' 
.variable var2, VARCHAR, '30'  
.executeCallableQuery 'var1,var2',   
 
select * from SCOTT.DEPT

More info here: https://www.aquaclusters.com/app/home/project/public/aquadatastudio/wikibook/Documentation14/page/196/Aqua-Commands

Comment: Hi, I tried "select var1, var2 from dual" with the code you provided above, but that didn't work.  How would you be able to use var1 and var2 in a SQL statement after they were created?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Parameterized Scripts to declare a variable in Aqua Data Studio, try using the following:

```
declare var1 varchar(20) := 'Hello world!';
begin
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(var1);
end;
```